# page downloads an unknown file called download without an unkown extension

Tags: phpmyadmin

UPDATE: ip/phpmyadmin does not go anywhere and then downloads a file every time the page loads.
When I tried this command, service mysqld status; it says '**mysqld: unrecognized service**'.

I've already tried to reinstall linux xampp. I'm still having the same problem.

PROBLEM:
I created a password in the phpmyadmin that is on the server and now I can't access the database.

This is what it says when I type address/phpmyadmin:
Error
MySQL said:

Cannot connect: invalid settings. 
phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

the server is centOs
I'm running linux XAMPP

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you have suPHP installed and that is not letting the pages be served from phpmyadmin because they are in the /usr/share/ directory which is restricted by suPHP from executing the pages here is a link to a workaroud https://serverfault.com/questions/211935/running-phpmyadmin-and-suphp

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you need to look at the configuration settings for phpMyAdmin.  These settings should allow it to connect to the database.  PhpMyAdmin needs this to validate any login attempts.

Comment: The thing is that it doesn't even ask me to attempt login. The error message is what occurs when I try to access the page.

Comment: The `config.inc.php` file has invalid or incorrect settings.  The error message in leyman's terms - There is an error with the configuration settings.  You have not typed in the hostname, username or the password correctly.

Can you confirm these settings are valid?

Comment: I have never configured config.inc.php. The only thing that I have done was to change the password in the phpmyadmin UI. When I tried this command, service mysqld status; it says 'mysqld: unrecognized service'.

Comment: Not sure if you have mysql installed!?  Can you confirm that it is installed? check the answers at http://serverfault.com/questions/69994/check-if-mysql-is-installed-on-server for hints.

Comment: I have been using this installation of phpmyadmin for months now. The only thing about it that I wanted changed was that it lets every computer access the tables and doesn't prompt the user for login information. So I assigned a password to the root user. I didn't do anything else but put a password which I did in the user interface of phpmyadmin.

Comment: I have misread your original post.  You are using Xampp and as such mysqld is not run as a service outside it. Xampp is designed for development use and should be quick to configure and get started.  You may want to undo the changes you have done - and ensure everything is working.  Then follow the security steps as detailed on the following page - http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html#381.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your configuration file for phpmyadmin.

config.inc.php
config-db.php

In config-db.php you can find MySQL login data for the user used by phpmyadmin to connect with database. Please use this credentials to log in from command line, if it is correct and you can log in, you should check config.inc.php. You will find there auth configuration:

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']
config - it will use credentials defined in the configuration file
cookie - prompts for a MySQL username and password
http - prompts for a MySQL username and password

If it is set to 'cookie' please clear web browser cache and try to login again. If you are unable to login please try to login using same credentials via command line.

Comment: I'm sorry but where can I find the file config-db.php?

Comment: You can find it in: /etc/phpmyadmin